# Get checkbox list values with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

In a div, I have some checkbox. I'd like when I push a button get all the name of all check box checked. Could you tell me how to do this ?

```
<div id="MyDiv">
....
<td><%= Html.CheckBox("need_" + item.Id.ToString())%></td>
...
</div>
```

Thanks,

Comment: Or '[boxen](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=boxen)' would also be accepted :P

Answer (score 83, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#someButton').click(function() {
        var names = [];
        $('#MyDiv input:checked').each(function() {
            names.push(this.name);
        });
        // now names contains all of the names of checked checkboxes
        // do something with it
    });
});
```

Comment: Why it's so easy when you give me the solution ?! ;-)

Comment: I was unable to get this array in the java, I used string[] but still. The error is when passing the variable via .post method. com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.logging.commons.CommonsLogger warn Error setting expression 'names[]' with value '[Ljava.lang.String;@4a004a0'

Comment: [You can also use `.map()`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1287592/get-checkbox-list-values-with-jquery/27956423#27956423).

Answer (score 10):

Since nobody has mentioned this..

If all you want is an array of values, an easier alternative would be to use the [**`.map()`**](http://api.jquery.com/map/) method. Just remember to call `.get()` to convert the jQuery object to an array:

[**Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/08oLtpcz/)

```
var names = $('.parent input:checked').map(function () {
    return this.name;
}).get();

console.log(names);
```

```js
var names = $('.parent input:checked').map(function () {
    return this.name;
}).get();

console.log(names);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="parent">
    <input type="checkbox" name="name1" />
    <input type="checkbox" name="name2" />
    <input type="checkbox" name="name3" checked="checked" />
    <input type="checkbox" name="name4" checked="checked" />
    <input type="checkbox" name="name5" />
</div>
```

Pure JavaScript:

[**Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/3pmxh1fq/)

```
var elements = document.querySelectorAll('.parent input:checked');
var names = Array.prototype.map.call(elements, function(el, i) {
    return el.name;
});

console.log(names);
```

```js
var elements = document.querySelectorAll('.parent input:checked');
var names = Array.prototype.map.call(elements, function(el, i){
    return el.name;
});

console.log(names);
```

```html
<div class="parent">
    <input type="checkbox" name="name1" />
    <input type="checkbox" name="name2" />
    <input type="checkbox" name="name3" checked="checked" />
    <input type="checkbox" name="name4" checked="checked" />
    <input type="checkbox" name="name5" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

```
var aArray = [];
window.$( "#myDiv" ).find( "input[type=checkbox][checked]" ).each( function()
{
  aArray.push( this.name );

});
```

You can put it in a function and execute on click of the button.

Answer (score 3):

Not tested but should work:

```
$("#MyDiv td input:checked").each(function()
{
    alert($(this).attr("id"));
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use map for this.

```
$('input[type=checkbox]:checked').map(function(i, e) { 
    return $(e).val(); 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this one..

```
var listCheck = [];
console.log($("input[name='YourCheckBokName[]']"));
$("input[name='YourCheckBokName[]']:checked").each(function() {
     console.log($(this).val());
     listCheck .push($(this).val());
});
console.log(listCheck);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var nameCheckBoxList = "myCheckListName";
var selectedValues = $("[name=" + nameCheckBoxList + "]:checked").map(function(){return this.value;});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this...

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $("button").click(function(){
            var checkBoxValues = [];
            $.each($("input[name='check_name']:checked"), function(){
                checkBoxValues.push($(this).val());
            });

            console.log(checkBoxValues);

        });
    });
```