# Saving all checkbox values from WebGrid in MVC 4

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-4

I am new to MVC 4. I am stuck in a situation and want some suggestions to resolve the problem. The problem scenario is:

I am rendering a WebGrid inside a partial view and the WebGrid format is as follows:
[image]

An IEnumerable collection is bound with the WebGrid. The view for binding WebGrid is:

```
@{    
MIS.Areas.AdminModule.Models.AdminModuleViewModels.Module_UserGrp_Permission allPermissions = new MIS.Areas.AdminModule.Models.AdminModuleViewModels.Module_UserGrp_Permission();
```

}

```
    @{
var grid = new WebGrid(Model, canPage: true, rowsPerPage: 10, selectionFieldName: "selectedRow", ajaxUpdateContainerId: "Title");
grid.Pager(WebGridPagerModes.NextPrevious);}
    <div id="gridContent">
        @grid.GetHtml(tableStyle: "webGrid",
            headerStyle: "header",
            alternatingRowStyle: "alt",
            selectedRowStyle: "select",
            columns: grid.Columns(
            grid.Column(header: "Select",
            format: @<input class="select" id="assignChkBx" name="assignChkBx" type="checkbox" @allPermissions.intMenuId/>),
            grid.Column(header: "MenuId", format: (item) => item.intMenuId, style: "description"),
            grid.Column(header: "Menu", format: (item) => item.strMenuName, style: "description", canSort: true),
            grid.Column(header: "Add", format: @<text><input name="Add" type="checkbox"  @(item.boolAddPer == true ? "Checked" : null) id="chkboxIsActiveAdd" /></text>),
            grid.Column(header: "Edit", format: @<text><input name="Edit" type="checkbox"  @(item.boolEditPer == true ? "Checked" : null) id="chkboxIsActiveEdit" /></text>),
            grid.Column(header: "Delete", format: @<text><input name="Delete" type="checkbox"  @(item.boolDeletePer == true ? "Checked" : null) id="chkboxIsActiveDelete" /></text>),
            grid.Column(header: "Grant", format: @<text><input name="Grant" type="checkbox"  @(item.boolGrantPer == true ? "Checked" : null) id="chkboxIsActiveGrant" /></text>)

     ))                       
    </div>
```

And fetching data from database as follows (I am NOT using EntityFramework) :

var result = from column in dt.AsEnumerable()

```
                     select new Module_UserGrp_Permission
                     {
                         intMenuId = Convert.ToInt32(column["MenuId"]),
                         intUserGrpId = Convert.ToInt32(column["UserGrpId"]),
                         strMenuName = Convert.ToString(column["MenuName"]),

                         boolAddPer = Convert.ToBoolean(column["boolGAdd"]),
                         boolEditPer = Convert.ToBoolean(column["boolGEdit"]),
                         boolDeletePer = Convert.ToBoolean(column["boolGDel"]),
                         boolViewPer = Convert.ToBoolean(column["boolGView"]),
                         boolGrantPer = Convert.ToBoolean(column["boolGGrant"])
                     };
        return new List<MIS.Areas.AdminModule.Models.AdminModuleViewModels.Module_UserGrp_Permission>(result);
```

Now the problem is I have to save all the checked/unchecked items from this WebGrid.
What should I do to save all the values after clicking the 'Save' button. 
Please suggest possible solutions.

Thank you all.

Answer (score 1):

Since all of your check boxes have the same name you can do a

```
string result = Request.Form["assignChkBx"].ToString();
```

on your controller which will give you a list of all of the checked checkboxes.  Hopefully this helps.

Comment: Thank you for your reply sir. I'll definitely give it a try. But you know I have to get all the checked/unchecked values from all the Add-Edit-Delete-Grant columns (the first select checkbox is not important as I have to take all the values). Also edited the checkbox names. I'll get back to you. Thanks..

Comment: Sir, following your suggestion I am able to get the values in 'on' format for checked items. But the problem is the values are not coming row wise, more over I can't get the unchecked values. So, how would I update all the values?

Comment: this is the easiest way to do it.  If you give each column its own name you can get a list of what is checked by doing a request on each name.  Since there are multiple on a row I would just query to get a list of available and compare with what is checked to get the unchecked

Comment: another option would be to compile the list using jquery.  you can get checked like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1287592/get-checkbox-list-values-with-jquery and unchecked like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8465821/find-all-unchecked-checkbox-in-jquery and then send the results to the controller with an ajax call

Answer (score 0):

While it's not a coded worked solution, I've managed to get this working with a single checkbox. Should be simple enough to get it wired up for multiple: [ASP.NET MVC Display an HTML Table with Checkboxes to Select Row Items](http://www.typecastexception.com/post/2014/01/05/ASPNET-MVC-Create-a-Table-with-Checkboxes.aspx)